# Selecting and displaying data from a custom table with UserSpice

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to UserSpice and I am trying to experiment with it.

I have created a custom table in my database holding colour codes for different distributors of my products.

I am trying to echo out the header and footer column using the following statement:

```
$db = DB::getInstance();
$customiseQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customise-distributor WHERE distributor = ". $parts[4] ."");
$customise = $customiseQ->first();

echo "Header Colour: ". $customise->header_colour ."";
```

I am not getting any errors but $customise->header_colour is blank.

Why would this be?

Comment: What does `var_dump($customise);` say?

Comment: @Albzi it seems to dump a query below further on the page? :S

Comment: It is because you did not properly bind your variables. Since the db class is using the singleton method, you can mix up your queries if you don't properly bind. It should be....$customiseQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customise-distributor WHERE distributor = ?",array($parts[4]));

Answer (score 0):

It is because you did not properly bind your variables. Since the db class is using the singleton method, you can mix up your queries if you don't properly bind. It should be....

$customiseQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customise-distributor WHERE distributor = ?",array($parts[4]));